# warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive

Tags: c++

I am compiling a quite a big project using VxWorks6.8 C++ compiler. I am getting following warning

warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive

```
#ifndef _OM_NO_IOSTREAM
#ifdef WIN32
#ifndef USE_IOSTREAM
#define USE_IOSTREAM
#endif USE_IOSTREAM
#endif WIN32
```

I am getting a quite a lot of these warnings.

> 1. Why i am getting these warnings and from C++ standard point of
>      view?
> 2. What is the good reason why compiler is warning for this?
> 3. What is the best way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
#endif USE_IOSTREAM
#endif WIN32
```

Should be:

```
#endif // USE_IOSTREAM
#endif // WIN32
```

`endif` doesn't take any arguments. Such comments are placed only for better readability.

You also missed closing `#endif // _OM_NO_IOSTREAM` at the end.

Comment: can u pls elobrate for what good reason compiler is throwing this warning? Thanks

Comment: Interestingly this solution does not work with `gfortran` (10.2.0) supplied with -cpp flag. However, with `gcc` it does.

Comment: @Addman: doesn't work how? please check that your "doesn't work" is related with the solution

Answer (score 18):

Because you can't have anything after `#endif`

Also, you're missing an endif.

```
#ifndef _OM_NO_IOSTREAM
  #ifdef WIN32
    #ifndef USE_IOSTREAM
      #define USE_IOSTREAM
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but you can have another `#if` block after the `#endif` though, right?

Comment: @MehdiCharife yeah I think I meant on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#endif USE_IOSTREAM
#endif WIN32
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Compiler is warning about these extra tokens after endif directive.
```

There is no need of any identifier after `#endif`. The way to suppress those warnings is to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't put text behind the #endif. (And you are missing an #endif for OM_NO_IOSTREAM)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
#ifndef YOUR_DEFINE
#define YOUR_DEFINE
// your code here
#endif // YOUR_DEFINE
```